# ssh not allowing passwordless login

Tags: ssh, sshd, key-authentication

I use passwordless logins all the time and have set it up on numerous systems and have debugged a lot of issues with it.  However, I'm in a situation that I can't diagnose the root cause.  I have an Ubuntu 18.04 server and Linux Mint 18.1 client.  I can use the same client to get passwordless login via RSA keys to other servers, so I don't suspect any issue on the client.  And the server is not allowing passwordless login to this Linux Mint client or another client (RHEL 7.3), so it's most likely a server configuration issue.  Since my username on the server is ubuntu, I checked the permissions of /home/ubuntu, /home/ubuntu/.ssh, and /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys and all are as expected.  I copied my ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub key over to the server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file as I also do.  When I try to ssh, I get the following logs on the server, and I don't see any errors reported there that would prohibit the RSA key login.

**Server DEBUG3 Logs**

```
debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Forked child 31422.
debug3: oom_adjust_restore
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 371
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.20.30.3 port 42760 on 10.20.30.2 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version SSH
debug1: no match: SSH
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: ssh_sandbox_init: preparing seccomp filter sandbox
debug2: Network child is on pid 31423
debug3: preauth child monitor started
debug3: privsep user:group 109:65534 [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 109/65534 [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: setting PR_SET_NO_NEW_PRIVS [preauth]
debug3: ssh_sandbox_child: attaching seccomp filter program [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 20 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug2: local server KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug2: peer client KEXINIT proposal [preauth]
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 [preauth]
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour [preauth]
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour [preauth]
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512 [preauth]
debug2: compression ctos: none [preauth]
debug2: compression stoc: none [preauth]
debug2: languages ctos:  [preauth]
debug2: languages stoc:  [preauth]
debug2: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
debug2: reserved 0  [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 34 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 0
debug3: mm_answer_moduli: got parameters: 2048 7680 8192
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 1
debug2: monitor_read: 0 used once, disabling now
debug3: mm_choose_dh: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_MODULI [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 1 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_choose_dh: remaining 0 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 31 [preauth]
debug2: bits set: 3906/7680 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 32 [preauth]
debug2: bits set: 3905/7680 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
debug3: mm_answer_sign
debug3: mm_answer_sign: hostkey proof signature 0x55689da150b0(271)
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
debug3: send packet: type 33 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 21 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0 [preauth]
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 5 [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 6 [preauth]
debug3: receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user ubuntu service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 8 [preauth]
debug3: mm_getpwnamallow: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 9 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 8
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 371
debug3: auth_shadow_acctexpired: today 18180 sp_expire -1 days left -18181
debug3: account expiration disabled
debug3: mm_answer_pwnamallow: sending MONITOR_ANS_PWNAM: 1
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 9
debug2: monitor_read: 8 used once, disabling now
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for ubuntu [preauth]
debug3: mm_inform_authserv entering [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 4 [preauth]
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug3: monitor_read: checking request 4
debug3: mm_answer_authserv: service=ssh-connection, style=, role=
debug2: monitor_read: 4 used once, disabling now
Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu 10.20.30.3 port 42760 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug3: mm_request_receive entering
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 31423
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

**Client Logs**

```
$ ssh -vvv ubuntu@10.20.30.2
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/clientuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "10.20.30.2" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.20.30.2 [10.20.30.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSH
debug1: no match: SSH
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.20.30.2:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/clientuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/clientuser/.ssh/known_hosts:252
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.20.30.2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,arcfour
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 34
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 4173/8192
debug3: send packet: type 32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 33
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:real_host_key_was_here
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/clientuser/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/clientuser/.ssh/known_hosts:252
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.20.30.2
debug1: Host '10.20.30.2' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/clientuser/.ssh/known_hosts:252
debug2: bits set: 4062/8192
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug2: key: /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55616bb74680), agent
debug2: key: /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x55616bb76e80)
debug2: key: /home/clientuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
debug3: start over, passed a different list password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@10.20.30.2's password:
```

**Server sshd_config**

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG3

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile  /home/%u/.ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes 
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

**Permissions**
On server:

```
ubuntu@test-ubuntu:~$ ls -l /home/ | grep ubuntu
drwx------ 10 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 11 16:25 ubuntu
ubuntu@test-ubuntu:~$ ls -al ~ | grep .ssh
drwx------  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Oct 11 16:45 .ssh
ubuntu@test-ubuntu:~$ ls -l ~/.ssh | grep authorized_keys
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1194 Oct 11 16:46 authorized_keys
```

On client:

```
clientuser@clienthost ~ $ ls -l /home | grep clientuser
drwx------ 88 clientuser  clientuser 4096 Oct 11 11:30 clientuser
clientuser@clienthost ~ $ ls -la ~ | grep .ssh
drwx------   3 clientuser clientuser      4096 Oct 11 11:46 .ssh
clientuser@clienthost ~ $ ls -l ~/.ssh | grep id_rsa
-rw------- 1 clientuser clientuser  1679 Feb  8  2018 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 clientuser clientuser   395 Feb  8  2018 id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Okay, reading over the (client-side) log it appears as if the server only ever offers `password` authentication. Could you please execute `$(which sshd) -T` (on the server-side) and post the _effective_ configuration (perhaps trimming sensitive data) rather than the one with commented out stuff? Because defaults may differ, depending on what the package maintainer has chosen.

Comment: Oh, and could you please also post the output of `ls -ld $HOME $HOME/.ssh $HOME/.ssh/id_* $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys|sed 's|'$(whoami)'|username|g'` (this will also redact your local username, provided the home directory is named after it also). Run this command _client-side_.

Answer (score 2):

The server offers the public key:

```
debug3: userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,password" [preauth]
debug3: send packet: type 51 [preauth]
```

but the client turns it down:

```
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password
```

Check `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (the *client side* global configuration) to see if

```
PubkeyAuthentication = yes
```

Also, since it seems to be a client-side issue, you might want to make the permissions of .ssh and all the files inside are right.

Comment: Perhaps `~/.ssh/config` is also worth a look ... in particular if the configuration makes use of wildcards that match, say, IP ranges or so ...

Comment: The client is able to ssh without password into other servers, so I don't suspect a client-side issue.  But just to check, I removed ~/.ssh/config and checked that PubkeyAuthentication is not present in the client's /etc/ssh/ssh_config, so it should take the default value of "yes"

Answer (score 0):

When you created the key-set, public and private, did you add a password to it? If so, this will request a password when you connect via ssh.

Please take a look at this link.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019999/key-based-ssh-login-that-requires-both-key-and-password

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I didn't add a password to the key, and I use the same key to log in to other servers without a password.

Comment: What are the permissions on ~/ and ~/.ssh? Setting `StrictModes` means group/other access to your ssh keys has to be restricted.

Comment: I added the permissions of all the related files to the end of the opening post.

Answer (score 0):

Now, *this* is not an answer to your specific problem, just a recipe I use whenever I am faced with puzzling issues like you have. This is a copy from [an answer I wrote on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/269753/11316).

To emphasize the benefits here:

1. faster "turnaround" ... you can pass configuration options (`-o OptionName=OptionValue`) on-the-fly without having to resort to editing the `sshd_config` file.
2. you may use an *alternative* copy of `sshd_config` (`-f ...`).
3. by using an alternative port you run less of a risk of locking yourself out if the remote server is only accessible via SSH.

---

### Troubleshooting `sshd`

What I find generally very useful in any such cases is to start `sshd` without letting it daemonize. The problem in my case was that neither `syslog` nor `auth.log` showed anything meaningful.

When I started it from the terminal I got:

```
# $(which sshd) -Ddp 10222
/etc/ssh/sshd_config line 8: address family must be specified before ListenAddress.
```

Much better! This error message allowed me to see what's wrong and fix it. Neither of the log files contained this output.

**NB:** at least on Ubuntu the `$(which sshd)` is the best method to satisfy `sshd` requirement of an absolute path. Otherwise you'll get the following error: `sshd re-exec requires execution with an absolute path`. The `-p 10222` makes `sshd` listen on that alternative port, overriding the configuration file - this is so that it doesn't clash with potentially running `sshd` instances. Make sure to choose a free port here.

This method has helped me many many times in finding issues, be it authentication issues or other types. To get really verbose output to `stdout`, use `$(which sshd) -Ddddp 10222` (note the added `dd` to increase verbosity). For more debugging goodness check `man sshd`.